# Estimation of Wasserstein distances

Tags: probability-theory, optimal-transport

This is a very specific question about [this optimal transport paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.07348.pdf), which addresses estimating the $2-$Wasserstein distance.  The authors write the transport cost explicitly for a specific type of coupling, and then proceed to omit terms in that expression when actually giving an estimate of the Wasserstein distance and I have no (good) idea why.  They do this as follows (you don't need to fully understand what the terms mean, just why they exclude the 2nd sum in the estimate):

[image]

Then they proceed to estimate the argmin of the above transport cost using:

[image]

where $P$ = $H$ = the barycenter, which is defined as

[image]

since the objective function of the barycenter problem is similar to the expression in prop. 4.2 (this is shown in proposition 4.3).  This is (somewhat) reasonable.  However, then they go on to say the following:

[image]

where the cost is just

[image]

Obviously this is just the first of the two sum terms and I'm confused as to why this is a valid idea.  I know they've made the statement that the second term is an "intra-cluster variance term" and the first is a "transport term", but don't they **sum up** to be the transport cost? So we shouldn't be ignoring one of them in our estimate?  Thanks if you're able to understand what's going on here, or have any of the insight I'm (clearly) missing.

Comment: Did you notice that they never use $\hat{W}$ again the paper? Their theory results of section 5 apply only to regular $W$. It's very weird. I guess the ad-hoc justification for removing the second sum is that it doesn't mix $C^{0}_j$ and $C{1}_j$. Otherwise, you're correct that $W$ is the sum of both terms.

Comment: I did.  This is why it confuses me so much throughout.  I feel like a lot of the details are perhaps rationally justifiable but the authors don't elaborate as to why.  I will probably send one of them an email to ask - and in the off chance they're interested in letting me know I'll update the post

Comment: I think the observation here is that the second term in the cost in Proposition 4.2 does not depend upon the coupling $\gamma$. The second term is completely determined by the marginals $P_i, I=0, 1$. It is therefore reasonable to think of the first term as the cost. That’s why they make a new definition.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho Thanks for looking at this! I see the intuition of wanting to label one term as a cost and one term as "irrelvant" with regard to the optimization problem itself, but I don't understand why it's valid to exclude it from the final estimate of the square Wasserstein distance.  If you were trying to estimate Wasserstein distance$^2$ - fixed term, then I'd be alright with their idea.

Comment: Perhaps it's justifiable if $$\sum_{j=1}^k \int \|x - \mu(C_j^i) \|^2 dC_j^i(x) \xrightarrow{k \rightarrow \infty} 0$$ for $i \in \{0,1\}$ and this would intuitively make sense.  Do either of you know if that's the case?